# Django - The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django

User can register without a profile image.
Now I get error that no file was associated with the login.

Why does it validate the form and then try to save the image?

It should not check for the image.

---

Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  90.         return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in form_valid
  119.         auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  161.     user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  193.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "/home/django/django_project/accounts/views.py" in got_online
  115.     user.profile.save()

File "/home/django/django_project/accounts/models.py" in save
  116.             img = Image.open(self.image.path)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in path
  64.         self._require_file()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in _require_file
  46.             raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /login/
Exception Value: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

---

accounts/models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path,null=True,blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserProfile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.image != None:
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)


def post_save_user_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        new_profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

---

The registration works without the user having a image, but the login does not.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a default image to the file field:

```
image               = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path,default='default.jpeg')
```

and by changing the if statement in the save method

from:

```
  if self.image != None:
```

to:

```
  if not self.image:
```

Comment: How does your media folder look like, or where you save your images?

Answer (score 0):

According to traceback, there is a signal receiver in `accounts/views.py#115`, that listens for `user_logged_in` signal and tries to save user profile:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  161.     user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
...
File "/home/django/django_project/accounts/views.py" in got_online
  115.     user.profile.save()
```

And in user profile save and tries to open the profile image to thumbnail it.